# Fourier inverse of $(\frac{1}{f(w)})$

Tags: fourier-analysis

I was using Fourier transform method to solve a non-linear differential equation and with $x(t)$ as the function I need to solve. Given that $F(x(t))=f(w)$, can we obtain a Fourier inverse of $F^{-1}(\frac{1}{f(w)})$ in terms of $x(t)$.

Comment: I don't understand why $F^-1(f)$ is not why you need.

Comment: Yes,but when i take the fourier transform of the entire differential equation,i end on one side second derivative of dirac delta function and on the other side F^-1(( f(w-a) + f(w+a))/f(w)). I used the convolution rule and found out the inverse of (f(w-a) + f(w+a)) but i had no clue about what could be F^-1(1/f(w)) which is needed to solve it. Help appreciated!

Comment: f() is any possible function ? otherwise dividing by f in Fourier is deconvolving is regular space, generaly an ill-posed operation (see debluring).  But if you know f, it might me that  f(w-a) + f(w+a))/f(w) simplifies.

Comment: We can assume that f(w) is well behaved and periodic but i cant take more thant i guess,isnt any generic comments possible ?

Comment: For a gauss filter (the most lovely easy function of all), $F^{-1}(\frac 1 {f(w)})$ is the strange filter that would unblur the signal. Good luck to get a close form ;-) . It could work only for very special f well adapted to the operation.

Comment: Okay!. I was trying to solve,x''=x cos(wt),using fourier transform method and ended up with above step,any hints?

Comment: what was the fourier transform you obtained, and the next steps you did ? (may be you should update the initial question with that).